# PostgreSQL Debugger installation

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to debug functions and tried many online articles but couldn't help myself in installing Debugger for PostgreSQL.

I'm using below version:

```
"PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit"
```

Can someone please assist me in installing Debugger for PostgreSQL?

Comment: which articles have you looked at to save someone looking at the same ones ?https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.8/debugger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull the latest source from https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pldebugger.git and build it according to the instructions in the README.

You'll need a configured PostgreSQL source installation, but that shouldn't be a problem because you compiled PostgreSQL yourself, didn't you?

Here are [the instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html) and [some remarks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation-platform-notes.html#INSTALLATION-NOTES-MINGW) for building with MinGW on Windows.

Comment: I'm complete new to Postgres. How do I access /contrib in windows? and copy the directory to this location.

Comment: Oh, I thought you'd built it yourself. Where did you get MinGW binaries?

Answer (score 0):

I am using postgresql 12 and pgadmin4 in my Microsoft Server. I tried to change postgresql config file (line 676) like:

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugins/plugin_debugger.dll'
```

and then I restarted postgresql-x64-12 service and my server. But it didn't work out. Then I learned that I don't have to change the config file. I just need to create an extension on the database I need. Extension's name is "pldbgapi". I explained with the images below. You just need to create this extension and then right-click on your function and debug it.

[Creating Extension (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhQv3.png)

[Creating Extension (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rExZC.png)

[Function Debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVZWy.png)

You can also create it with command line.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi
SCHEMA public
VERSION "1.1";
```